# Валидация при добавлении полей через ajax?

Tags: yii2

вот правила валидации в модели

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_id', 'city_id', 'payment',], 'required'],
            ['street', 'required', 'message' => 'Укажите название улицы.'],
            ...
        ];
    }
```

вот так я создаю форму

```
<div class="radio radio-tab">
        <label><input id="delivery1" type="radio" name="Order[delivery]" checked="" value="0"> Самовывоз </label>
</div>
 <div class="radio radio-tab">
             <label> <input id="delivery2" type="radio" name="Order[delivery]" value="1"> Доставка  </label>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
           <div class="tab-pane delivery1 active">  ... </div>
           <div class="tab-pane delivery2"> </div>
           ...
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

таким образом формирую ajax запрос

```
$('.radio-tab input').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
       if(id=='delivery1'){ ... })
       if(id=='delivery2')
           $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/cart/delivery",
            data: true,
            success: function (data) {
               ...
                $('.radio-tabs .tab-pane.delivery2').html(data);
                $('.radio-tabs .tab-pane.delivery2').addClass('active');
            }
        })
```

так обрабатываю его в контролере

```
public function actionDelivery(){
        $model=new Order();
        return $this->renderAjax('_deliveryPiter',[
            'model'=>$model,
        ]);
    }
```

и вот так вывожу

```
...
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group field-order-street <?= $model->isAttributeRequired('street') ? 'required' : '' ?>">
                <?= Html::activeLabel($model,'street'); ?>
                <?= Html::activeInput('text',$model,'street',['class'=>'form-control']) ?>
            </div>
...
        </div>
```

и вроде все выводится но вопрос с валидацией на клиенте остался открытым. То есть если инпут не заполнен, не выводиться сообщение об ошибке, и не правильно заполненная форма отправляется на сервер где соответственно валидация на серевере не проходит. Вопрос как можно организовать вылидацию на клиенте.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте код вашей формы: в вашем примере не видно `<div class="help-block"></div>`, обычно в него попадают сообщения об ошибках. в `ActiveForm::begin([])` можно передать параметры **enableClientValidation**, **enableAjaxValidation**

Если вы передали `enableAjaxValidation = true`, то вам необходимо будет валидировать модель, пришедшую ajax запросом, *см. пример* **performAjaxValidation**

```
public function actionDelivery(){
        $model=new Order();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) {
            $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
        }
        return $this->renderAjax('_deliveryPiter',[
            'model'=>$model,
        ]);
}

protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && !Yii::$app->request->isPjax) {
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                echo json_encode(ActiveForm::validate($model));
                Yii::$app->end();
            }
        }
    }
```